# Go will not use my ssh key when contacting our bitbucket repo

Tags: git, go

I can execute 'git clone' and run git commands all day in the repo connecting with my private key, but the minute Go tries to connect, I get permission denied. What changes do I need to make to have go pass along my private key? This is the error running 'go mod tidy'.

```
go: finding module for package bitbucket.<org>.com/projects/IE/repos/snowgo
script.go imports
        bitbucket.<org>.com/projects/IE/repos/snowgo: module bitbucket.<org>.com/projects/IE/repos/snowgo: git ls-remote -q origin in /home/userName/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/d77154404425fd517045ab48bdcdb88edd7826424ee09812d46ddb0d47f6ffd6: exit status 128:
        git@bitbucket.<org>.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
        fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

        Please make sure you have the correct access rights
        and the repository exists.
```

I have this (now) in my ~/.gitconfig.user file

```
[url "ssh://git@bitbucket.<org>.com/"] 
      insteadOf = https://bitbucket.<org>.com
```

/

This is my go env:

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/myUserName/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/myUserName/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/myUserName/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/myUserName/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/lib/golang"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/golang/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.20.10"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/home/myUserName/credsy/go.mod"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_FFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-O2 -g"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build4073654673=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Thanks for taking a look! Let me know if there are some commands that would be helpful for RCA.

Comment: Does that Bitbucket Server instance listen on port 22 or something different?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `insteadOf` workaround, try:

1. Run `git config --global credential.helper store`
2. Try again

The docs say you're not supposed to touch the file, and it'll just add credentials as-needed to `~/.config/git/credentials`.

I think you could also use a personal access token instead of a password here. Depends on what BitBucket supports.

See documentation for [git-credential-store](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store) (`git help credential-store`).

Comment: Didn't help. I removed the insteadOf and tried this. Similar error, but now  'fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.myorg.com': terminal prompts disabled
Confirm the import path was entered correctly.' Like now its trying to do an http login.

Comment: **Without** re-enabling the `insteadOf`, try (from your local user shell): `git clone https://bitbucket.<org>.com/projects/IE/repos/snowgo` - enter the username and password. This should create ~/.config/git/credentials. If it doesn't ask you for a password (it should), then you're gonna have to try it on a different user account (e.g. root's terminal).